# VBA sorting table in other workbook

Tags: excel, excel-tables, vba

Good morning,

I have a macro that, among other things, sorts a table in another workbook.  Here's the relevant bits of code

```
Set wbLSHP = Workbooks("CDU_Enrollee Engagement Tracking Report v2.2.xlsx")
Set wsLSHP = wbLSHP.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

"wsLSHP" is the worksheet where the table is located.  The table is named "Table1"

```
wsLSHP.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
wsLSHP.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.add _
    Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[CHW First Name]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With wsLSHP.ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

When running this, I get the following error: 
"Run-time error '1004':, Application-defined or object-defined error

This happens at the following line:

```
wsLSHP.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.add _
Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[CHW First Name]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Any ideas on what's causing this error?

Comment: Is the `wsLSHP` opened, when you are getting the error?

Comment: The file is open.  I'm getting the error at the line listed above, when the macro attempts to sort the table.

Comment: What is the idea of  this - `("Table1[[#All],[CHW First Name]]")`

Comment: Oh that's probably why it's happening.  That came from recording the macro in the wsLSHP sheet, but since this is being run in a different workbook maybe it can't process that range.  I'll try to change it and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, added a dynamic range instead ("Table1[[#All],[CHW First Name]]") and that did the trick.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome :)